# Numerical Optimizer Matlab Calibration

Tags: optimization, matlab, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, constraints

I am trying to mimimize the following function in order to calibrate the Libor Market Model

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\sigma_i^{market}-\sigma_i^{Reb}\left(a,b,c,d,\beta\right)/\sqrt{T_i}\right)^2,$$

where $\sigma_i^{market}$ is given and $\sigma_i^{Reb}\left(a,b,c,d,\beta\right)$ is a nonlinear function in the unknown parameters $a,b,c,d,\beta$.

The parameters should have the following constraints:
$$a+d>0$$
$$d>0$$
$$c>0$$
$$\beta \geq 0$$
Which numerical optimizer method in Matlab would be a good candidate such that the constraints are satisfied?

I tried to implement the calibration with the unconstraint local optimizer fminsearch based on the Downhill-simplex algorithm. Nevertheless, with different choices of initial values of the parameters, the algorithm converges to parameters that do not respect the constraints.

So I decided to try a constrained numerical optimizer, the non linear least squares method (lsqnonlin) in Matlab with as lowerbounds 0 for the last three constraints. However, I do not know how to impose constraint number 1 with this method. Does someone have any suggestions?

Would the (unconstrained?) Levenberg Marquardt be a good candidate? Other ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be, you could first redefine three parameters setting :$d=\delta^2$, $c=\gamma^2$, $\beta=\eta^2$ and see what happens.using $\delta,\gamma,\eta$ as parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. I assume that parameter $a$ has to be set to $a =\psi^2$. What would be the intuition behind this? So that calibrated negative values of the parameters are not involved? The same however problem arises, which optimization method is the best suitable for this kind of problem such that all constraits are satisfied?

Comment: Not for $a$ since $a+\delta^2>0$ does not imply $a>0$. In my opinion, you have to work with constrained optimization methods.